# Finding difference of two plots in C#

Tags: c#, c++, plot, subtraction, curves

I am having a laser scanner application where I want to find the difference between two plots ,one the reference plot without object and the other with the object in view.I am plotting the graph with x y coordinates. currently I have plotted the graphs and filled them with different colors so that I can view the subtracted part clearly. But now I want only the difference area to show up...I thought finding the area under the curve will solve the issue.But I think it will only give the numerical value and not the exact position of the subtracted area.

So,I searched the internet looking for solutions in C# where I can do this in the plot itself.Hope I made myself clear.
Can someone guide me in the search?  I am giving my c# code here..

```
// PointPairList holds the data for plotting, X and Y arrays (one can use other types of objects as well)

        PointPairList spl1 = new PointPairList(x1, y1);
        PointPairList spl2 = new PointPairList(x2, y2);
        PointPairList spl3 = new PointPairList(x, y);



// Add curves to myPane object
      LineItem myCurve1 = myPane.AddCurve("LIDAR Data Scanner-Measurement-Normal", spl1, Color.Blue, SymbolType.None);
      LineItem myCurve2 = myPane.AddCurve("LIDAR Data Scanner-Measurement-with object", spl2, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);
      LineItem myCurve3 = myPane.AddCurve("LIDAR Data Scanner-Measurement-Subtracted curve", spl3, Color.Green, SymbolType.None);

    //   myCurve1.Line.Width = 3.0F;
    //myCurve2.Line.Width = 3.0F;
    myCurve1.Line.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.FromArgb(16, 155, 0, 0), 90F);
    myCurve2.Line.Fill = new Fill(Color.Black, Color.FromArgb(143, 55, 6, 0), 90F);
```

I want to display only the rectangle white part in the figure...

[image]

Comment: Why tag this as c++ and c# when you are only talking about c#?

Comment: @Aleks if it is possible in c++,I can do it there also..

Comment: What kind of curve do you want to get ? Subtracted curve like this one? http://ars.sciencedirect.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0304395901002950-gr1.gif

Comment: @DmitriyReznik Thanks for the suggestion. I have now added the graph in my question. the blue curve is the reference one.. the red one exactly overlaps except at the object position.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about data-structures that you are sighted - however, generally speaking, if you are dealing with polygons (closed curves specifies with a set of x,y points) then you can do polygon clipping to find the difference. See

[Algorithm to Compute the Remaining Polygon After Subtraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458567/algorithm-to-compute-the-remaining-polygon-after-subtraction)
[How to intersect two polygons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526352/how-to-intersect-two-polygons)

If you can represent your two plots i.e. a reference plot and supplied plot as polygon then above algorithm should allow you compute the difference.

Comment: I tried the GPC algorithm. But it is only for the integers. But I have double values..

Comment: @lakshmikant, GPC might be using integer coordinates but transform coordinate systems is not that difficult. If you know the range and precision of your values then converting them into/from integers is straight-forward. For example, your doubles are in from say 0 to 10 with 5 digits after decimal the multiplying with 100000 should give you integer values - multiplier can be different for x,y - same to be used when converting ints back to double.